# Siblings of a Tikz tree don't align properly

Tags: tikz-pgf

It appears that the siblings of a tree I made in Tikz don't align properly. The text line for each sibling level doesn't seem right.

I'm not sure how to fix this; thanks for any help.

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=8cm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=4cm},level 3/.style={sibling distance=2cm}]
\node {Buying a car}
 child {node {Red}
  child {node {Cloth}
   child {node {Standard}}
   child {node {Upgraded}}}
  child {node {Leather}
   child {node {Standard}}
   child {node {Upgraded}}}}
 child {node {Blue}
  child {node {Cloth}
   child {node {Standard}}
   child {node {Upgraded}}}
  child {node {Leather}
   child {node {Standard}}
   child {node {Upgraded}}}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Options when buying a car.}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead put your fragment into a complete compilable document that people can play with.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like

```
every node/.append style={anchor=mid}
```

added to the options you pass `tikzpicture`.

[image: aligned nodes]

Or Forest aligns them by default:

```
\documentclass[border=9pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [Buying a car
    [Red
      [Cloth
        [Standard]
        [Upgraded]
      ]
      [Velvet
        [Standard]
        [Upgraded]
      ]
  ]
  [Blue
      [Cloth
        [Standard]
        [Upgraded]
      ]
      [Velvet
        [Standard]
        [Upgraded]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: cruelty-free alignment]

Answer (score 2):

The descenders of the letters `p` and `g` in `Upgraded` force the node to be higher than `Standard`, whose letters do not have descenders. You can fix this by adding the option `anchor=north` to the nodes, which will align the siblings as they have the same cap height.

Another solution is to put `\vphantom{p}` after `Standard` in every such node, which provides a vertical space the height of the letter `p` with no horizontal width.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the descenders of the letters like p and g. Another solution is to use `text depth` option in TikZ.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an example to use the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package:

[image]

**Revised**: To correct the alignment of the last texts, I inserted `[text depth=.25ex]`and exchanged the picture accordingly.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}
\tikzset{oval node/.style={ellipse node,draw=none}}
% start
\xtdistance{15mm}{80mm}
\istrooto(0){Buying a car} \istb \istb \endist
% Red or Blue
\xtdistance{15mm}{40mm}
\istrooto(1)(0-1){Red} \istb \istb \endist
\istrooto(2)(0-2){Blue} \istb \istb \endist
% Cloth or Leather
\xtdistance{15mm}{20mm}
\istrooto(a)(1-1){Cloth} \istb \istb \endist
\istrooto(b)(1-2){Leather} \istb \istb \endist
\istrooto(c)(2-1){Cloth} \istb \istb \endist
\istrooto(d)(2-2){Leather} \istb \istb \endist
% Standard or Upgrade
\foreach \x in {a,b,c,d}
{
\istrooto(A)(\x-1)[text depth=.25ex]{Standard} \endist % revised
\istrooto(B)(\x-2)[text depth=.25ex]{Upgrade} \endist  % revised
}
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```